# Using npm with an MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, npm

I am getting a bit confused here.

I have an `MVC` 5 project, I want to use the `npm` for managing my javascript packages.

I installed `npm` from `nuget` and here i am stuck, I cant find the commandline console window or anything like that.

All the info i see online is about node projects.

Can someone direct me to a relevant tutorial.

Using visual studio 2013, MVC 5.

Comment: This might help you get started - https://medium.com/@jonjam/combining-webpack-with-asp-net-mvc-5-a5bd07c49d0b

Answer (score 12):

Well regardless of the project, if you want to use `npm` on Windows, this is what you need:

1. Download and install [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) (you might need a restart).
2. Make sure that node is installed by opening a command prompt and running `node -v` (should print a version number).
3. Run `npm -v` and see if it's installed (should be).

Now in the context of an ASP.NET MVC project. The newer versions of Visual Studio (I believe 2015) support `npm` - you can just open the `package.json` and add dependencies (it will download them behind the scenes). In case you're using an old version, you can simply open a command prompt, navigate to your project and use `npm install` from there.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Even in 2017 it seems to be a manual process or rely upon third party extensions and configuration

Comment: @IronSean I have to admit, I use VSCode for node projects, however I just opened VS2017 and although a bunch of things have changed, I still see plenty of integrations (Add New Item -> npm Configuration File), or right-click on a `package.json` file and "restore packages", or open the `package.json` and right click on individual packages/dependencies and update/uninstall them or go to their homepage etc. Also autocomplete packages when you type them (along with their version). So ya I think this still applies. Do you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: How is this meant to work when publishing an ASP.NET MVC 5? In my project I am referencing the node_modules folder in my BundleConfig. When I publish the files the contents of the node_modules doesn't come with it because it's not part of my solution.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher Typically you would have a build setup that bundles your app in a JS output file (webpack for example) and you deploy that.